# Give private key ownership to user without /home

Tags: ssh, sftp, chown, private-key

so I am looking to set up ssh private/public keys between two servers, for use with sftp (and ultimately lftp using sftp - but one step at a time).

I have created the private and public keys, and found that in order to use them, the private key must be owned and only readable by the user connecting.

The problem is, the user I am connecting as doesn't have a /home/ directory on either server (and only exists on the remote server), so when I try to `chown`, I get `chown: invalid user: {userName}` - because it doesn't exist locally.

Can anyone suggest a way around this?

--Edit--

I used `getent passwd` on both servers, and found that the user only exists on the server I'm `sftp`ing *to*. So when I connect as that user (`sftp weirdUser@remoteHost`), how can I do this using private/public keys?

Comment: Here is a guide from Ubuntu [Troubleshooting SSH with encrypted home dir](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Troubleshooting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `~/.ssh/config` file on your local server that will associate your key with the user on the remote server such as:

```
Host yourremoteserver
    User weirduser
    IdentityFile /home/mylocaluser/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If you want to create a unique key just for weirduser@yourremoteserver use the `-f` option on ssh-keygen:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1024 -f weirduser
```

and replace the IdentifyFile line in the `~/.ssh/config` file with:

```
IdentityFile /home/mylocaluser/.ssh/weirduser
```

Whichever key you decide to use (the default id_rsa or weirduser), you'll need the contents of the corresponding .pub file inserted into weirduser's `authorized_keys` on the remote server. After you have your config file setup, try (it'll prompt for the remote password then copy the .pub file to the correct `authorized_keys`):

```
ssh-copy-id weirduser@yourremoteserver
```

(Or you could do this manually)

Comment: That's exactly where my error was - I did it for the wrong user. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you need to create the user SSH private/public key is just another method of authentication instead of password authentication.

So you need to create the user that is allowed to use the public private key pair
http://www.tecmint.com/add-users-in-linux/

Create the user then you can CHOWN to that user.

Comment: but the user exists (as I understand it, I didn't set up the server), it just doesn't have a /home directory and you can't log in as it - it's only intended for use in connecting over (S)FTP to another server.

Comment: BUT (S)FTP is SSH so if you can't login as that user it can't exist. i would speak to them

Comment: I can use `sftp weirdUser@host`, type the password, and log in fine - but the user doesn't exist as far as I can see (using `getent passwd`), so I can't give it a private key file

Comment: OK, just found it on the other server... so how do i give it the private key when it only exists on the server I'm connecting to?

Comment: You need to download the key from the server https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sftp-to-securely-transfer-files-with-a-remote-server however i would speak to them as they have created the user but it's directory is not set to /home/user

Comment: wouldn't that mean that both the public and private keys would be on the remote server then? How does that authenticate who is connecting?

Comment: the remote Server has both as its the server that generated the pair, and the connecting client only has the private key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31047/discussion-between-martin-barker-and-simonalexander2005).

Comment: Ok, to be clear, key pairs should only ever be generated by the person who will be using them, and generated on the system they'll be connecting from. Private jeys are truly private, and should be protected as if they are your password. Public keys on the other hand, do not need to be protected at all.